# Bluetooth audio doesn't work - Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluetooth-speaker

I'm having problems regarding a bluetooth speaker. 
It does connect with the system, in the bluetooth setting I can see that the device is connected, but I can not see the option to select external speakers as output sound. 
I've got pulseaudio and blueman installed and yet even the device is connected I can not hear sound coming out.

Did anyone have the same problem?

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After successful connecting of the bluetooth speaker, try
`sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

If that then allows you to select the speaker as an output device, you can make the following changes:

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment out the following lines:

```
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

Then in:

```
nano /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

Find the following lines and add after them:

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
fi

# Add the following lines:
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
# /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect #<-- Uncomment to automatically select speaker on connection
```